# Train rasa x through Http api postman

Tags: api, postman, rasa, rasa-x

I want to train rasa x through http api in their docs but getting an internel server error.I am pasting the screenshots of my error, if anyone can help it will be benficial[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElYbZ.png)